# Update a "Box and Whisker" chart with new "Source Data" in a dynamic range

Tags: excel

I am using Excel 2016 and want to update a "Box and Whisker" chart with new "Source Data" in a dynamic range.
One workaround is to delete "Chart 1" and create a new "Box and Whisker" chart but how to update existing chart?
I have tried below code and others but I can't get it to work without using "On Error Resume Next - On Error GoTo 0" before and after last line in macro.
It seems only I have problem with this "Box & Whisker" chart so maybe it's not the macro causing the error. When I change to other chart types like: "Column", "Line", and "Pie", and run code, it works!

```
Sub UpdateChartData()
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = ActiveSheet.Columns("A:G").Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).row
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate    'added by soidog
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=ActiveSheet.range(ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(LR, 7))
End Sub
```

Please follow my effort solving this problem at:
"https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1109034-update-chart-sourcedata-dynamic-range-2.html?s=3e947d6afe969e2cbebc4fb73b165bda"

Now I have installed Excel 2016 on another computer and tried my code and also updated to Excel 2019 on my computer, but I still get: "Runtime error 445, Object doesn't support this action", at last line in code.
When I check with Microsoft support they refer to your site to get help with this.
What am I doing wrong?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I tried helping on MrExcel, too. Could you post your actual workbook with the offending chart? Because I tried to replicate your situation, and I did not have the problem you're having. Did you try with a new workbook?

Comment: Jon Peltier I have tried with a new workbook. Same result. I can't find the option to post a workbook on this site. Basically row 1-3 have text. Row 4-15 have numbers between 1-20 in each cell (columns A:G). I add a number in A16 and run the code which generate the error.

Comment: You would have to post your workbook on a file sharing site.

Answer (score 0):

I have run the code repeatedly on an Excel box plot, without the error reported in the question.

I am familiar with the error. It is common in the newer Excel charts (waterfall, box and whisker, etc.), and you will get it if you try to copy the chart with VBA using these common statements:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart1").Copy
```

or

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart1").Chart.ChartArea.Copy
```

I have simplified the code to the following, which would not help the error anyway, but streamlines the code and prevents selection of objects.

```
Sub UpdateChartData()
  With ActiveSheet
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = .Columns("A:G").Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
    .ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=.Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(LR, 7))
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: File uploaded at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hc62l8f4aogcmxq/Book1.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Thanks for your time Jon Peltier, I guess we have to leave it there. If I understand it right, it's only Microsoft who can fix this bug for newer versions of Excel. I'll continue to create new charts at update. It's not a big deal and it gets my job done.

Comment: Did you try putting the data into a Table (my other answer)? This is a best practice for any chart's data, since it automatically updates things without needing a tedious manual approach, or in your case, a faulty VBA approach.

Comment: I'm not sure it's really an Excel bug. Using Excel 2016 (version 1908, build 11929.20254) on another laptop (not the newer Office 365 I used for my previous answers), the code runs as I've written it here, adding the new data without encountering any errors. There may be a problem with your installation, or maybe you need to apply whatever updates may be available for Excel 2016.

Comment: Hmmm, I didn't notice your edit until after my latest comments. In my testing, Office 2016 and Office 365 do not have the error. I do not have Office 2019, but Office 365 is newer anyway. I also didn't see the download link, so I'll check your file here.

Comment: Using your workbook, Office 2016 and Office 365 run the code (my reworked procedure as well as your original one) without error.

Comment: I have tried putting the data into a Table and that works. Chart is updating automatically when I add or remove data.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually make the chart respond to added data without VBA.

Select A3:G15 (or G-last-row), and press Ctrl+T to convert the range into a Table. Row 3 becomes the header row of the table. If the chart is already using this range for its data, you're good. Or you could select the data rows of the Table and recreate the chart.

[image: Excel Table and Box Plot]

When you add data to the row below the Table (cell G16 below), it expands to include the new data in this row, and any formula in the workbook that references a whole column of the Table will automatically update as well. This includes the SERIES formulas in your charts.

[image: Expanded Excel Table and Box Plot]